# Nunit Test fails with Exceptions even when ExpectedException attribute is there

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have this simple test

```
 [Test]
 [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
 public void Test2()
 {
     throw new Exception();
 }
```

as I knew this test shoudln't be failed because I am expcted to see such an exception, but it fails with this error

```
Test Name:  Test2
Test FullName:  Framework.Tests.Service.BaseServiceTest.Test2
Test Source:    c:\Framework.Tests\Service\BaseServiceTest.cs : line 75
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.189

Result StackTrace:  at Framework.Tests.Service.BaseServiceTest.Test2() in c:\Framework.Tests\Service\BaseServiceTest.cs:line 76
Result Message: System.Exception : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

I have tried with other types of exceptions too, and result is the same

Comment: Since you are using ExpectedException and the code compiles, you must be referencing NUnit V2, although you have tagged this as nunit-3.0. If you are running the code using V2, it should pass. What are you actually using to run the code?

Comment: and for the same reason Charlie's brought up, you'd be better off using `Assert.Throws(()=>MethodThatThrows());` instead of that obsolete attribute.

Comment: @Charlie I am using NUnit3.4 and find out the ExpectedException is not comming from nunit namespace it's from mstest, And I couldn't find ExpectedException in NUnit3 so, as Alexandru says it seems its obsolete, finally I changed my code to use Assert.Throws<>